# Using CSS only I need to hide a DIV on 1 page only

Tags: wordpress, css

WordPress install 4.61, Sydney Theme
http://www.benpaddlejones.com

On the home page (slug is home) I need to hide this div:

How to I define the class or id specific to this page?

(I know how to do {display: none;})

I've tried a few things and get nothing I'm pretty sure it's how I'm define the class?

Ben :-)

Comment: `body` home page has a class `.home`, you may use it as a selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress automatically adds a class to the body based on the ID of the page, the name is something like 'page-27' or something simular, so apply this CSS

```
.page-<id> .item { 
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: here, on home page you have theses classes used on the site : <body class="home page page-id-2 page-template-default"> , i believe the best is to select `.home` unless you want to select `.page-id-2` even if it is not anymore the home page ;) *(just look at the source to find out which are the class generated by wordpress )*

Comment: GCyrillus is very much right! It all depends on your preferences :)